# SSIS - Variable truncated/converted when passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm working on an SSIS package that gets data from a CSV file, where there is 1 column, and the data from each row is passed as an argument to a stored procedure. Each row is 9 numbers and 1 letter (i.e. a 10 char string).

The structure of the package goes like this:

```
For loop that iterates over files in a given directory.
Data Flow ( Flat File Source getting CSV file -> Recordset Destination )
-> For loop that iterates over each record.
Execute SQL Task calls stored procedure with the value from each record as a parameter.
```

The problem:

Based on debug code in the stored procedure, this is what is passed:

`Actual data: 111111111X, 222222222Y, 333333333Z.
What's received: 1, 2, 3.`

I added some breakpoints and watched the variable being used to store the string, and I can see it's value during each iteration is correct, i.e. the full 10-char string, before and after the stored procedure call.

Based on some googling, this leads me to think there is some type conversion happening between the time the data is passed from the variable to the Execute SQL Task and the call is made.

This link indicates that the task will cast data sometimes:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/eadaee01-33b0-47f3-8702-34a40d2fe333/debug-execute-sql-task-what-parameter-value-is-passed

I've ruled out type/length nonsense and the watched variable confirms. I've also tried casting in the statement itself, to no avail.

Can anyone confirm my hypothesis and/or offer a solution?

Comment: What type of connection manager are you using with the Execute SQL Task? OLE DB? And what are the types of the parameters in the parameter tab of the Execute SQL Task ?

Comment: Please also provide your sql statement (the call to the SP)

Comment: Sorry, ODBC. Statement: {call NameOf_StoredProcedure(?)}

Comment: What are the types of the parameters in the parameter tab of the Execute SQL Task ?

Comment: One parameter:
Type: SQL_VARCHAR
Parameter name: 1
Parameter size: 10

I've also tried with SQL_CHAR, i.e. fixed length.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this, but I did replace the Execute SQL Task with a Script Task, and implemented the stored procedure call in code. Debugging in the script tells me what I already new i.e. the strings are coming through fine. I surmise that the SQL task was doing some sort of implicit conversion and losing some of the data in the process.

Answer (score 0):

it may occur EVEN when:

check if your source flat file is a UNICODE file
AND

set your target column is defined as nvarchar(max).